# jquery - load different divs from a external page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and I want load from page load.php the text for each div in this page 
**only with a load request from page load.php**.

The example below load the page load.php twice :(

```
$('#div1').load('load.php #div1');
$('#div2').load('load.php #div2');

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

---

load.php page  I have the code code:

```
<div id="div1">test to load1</div>
<div id="div2">test to load2</div>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Code shown should do what you ask (assuming the elements exist when you run that code). You haven't specified a real problem in the question

Comment: The problem is that load 2x the page load.php

Comment: Suggest you take a few minutes to help us help you by reading [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You could load the php using `jQuery.get` and then insert each fragment in to the desired elements:

```
$.get({
    url: 'page.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {
        var html = $($.parseHTML(response));
        $('#div1').text(html.filter('#div1').text());
        $('#div2').text(html.filter('#div2').text());
    }
});
```

**Edit/note** if the elements (`#div1` and `#div2`) are at the top level of the loaded html, use: `html.filter('#div1')`; otherwise use `html.find('#div1')` to select the desired node.

More about [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Comment: @FullDISK Are the DIVs really at the top level of the output of `page.php`, or are they inside some other elements? If they're nested you need to use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`.

Comment: @Barmar depends on the output. I think i will add a note on that. Thanks!